# How to create 3 domain relationships in Grails 3?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

I have 3 domain class and I need to define their relationships but I find no luck in defining them correctly. Can somebody rectify my code? I have always get the error unknown column pointing to an id. Please help. Below are my codes. Thank you.

**Todo.groovy class**

```
package todoScaff

import userScaff.User
import categoryScaff.Category

class Todo {

String name
String note
Date createDate
Date dueDate
Date completedDate
String priority
String status
User owner
Category category

static belongsTo = [User, Category]

static constraints = {
    name(blank:false)
    createDate()
    priority()
    status()
    note(maxsize:1000, nullable:true)
    completedDate(nullable:true)
    dueDate(nullable:true)
}


 String toString() {
    name
 }


}
```

**Category.groovy class**

```
package categoryScaff

import todoScaff.Todo
import userScaff.User

class Category {

String name
String description
User user
static belongsTo = User
static hasMany = [todos: Todo]


static constraints = {
    name(blank:false)
}

 String toString(){
    name
 }

}
```

**User.groovy class**

```
package userScaff

import todoScaff.Todo
import categoryScaff.Category

class User {

String userName
String fname
String lname

static hasMany = [todos: Todo, categories: Category]

static constraints = {

    userName(blank:false, unique:true)
    fname(blank:false)
    lname(blank:false)
}

 String toString(){
    "$lname, $fname"
 }

}
```

**Errors**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Include your SQL table structure (names of tables and columns)

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain your SQL tables are incorrect.

I created a small project with your 3 domain classes and used the grails command `schema-export`; after removing everything that doesn't relate to the domain relationship, the structure should look like this:

```
create table category (
    id bigint,
    user_id bigint,
);
create table todo (
    id bigint,
    category_id bigint,
    owner_id bigint,
);
create table user (
    id bigint
);
```

If your table structure doesn't resemble this, you should either change it to match or use the `static mapping = {}` closure in the domain class to indicate the proper column names.

**Static Mapping**
In `Todo`:

```
static mapping = {
    owner column: 'owner_id' // change owner_id to match your owner column within todo
    category column: 'category_id' // change category_id to match your category column within todo
}
```

In `Category`:

```
static mapping = {
    owner user: 'user_id' // change user_id to match your user column within category
}
```